# django-rest-registration 0.5.1 throws RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_URL and RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_URL are not set, even if they are set

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-authentication

I am creating REST api, with Django Rest Framework, and first of all I have to give users the way to register. I saw django-rest-registration as easy way to make this, but when I did everything as is said in [Quickstart](https://django-rest-registration.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), my terminal throws those errors:

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (rest_registration.E001) RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_URL is not set
?: (rest_registration.E004) VERIFICATION_FROM_EMAIL is not set

System check identified 2 issues (0 silenced).
```

Here's my code:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',

    'rest_registration',

    'app',
]

REST_REGISTRATION = {
    'REGISTER_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
    'REGISTER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
    'RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_ENABLED': False,
}
```

urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app.urls')),
     path('accounts/', include('rest_registration.api.urls')),
]
```

But, when I tried to change `REST_REGISTRATION` to this:

```
REST_REGISTRATION = {
    'REGISTER_VERIFICATION_URL': 'https://frontend-host/verify-user/',
    'RESET_PASSWORD_VERIFICATION_URL': 'https://frontend-host/reset-password/',
    'REGISTER_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_URL': 'https://frontend-host/verify-email/',

        'VERIFICATION_FROM_EMAIL': 'no-reply@example.com',
    }
```

and I submitted the request, I saw another error:

ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/
+ Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/accounts/register/

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'corsheaders',
 'rest_registration',
 'app']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  495.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  455.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  492.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
  55.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_registration/api/views/register.py" in register
  96.         send_verification_notification(user, signer, template_config)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_registration/notifications/email.py" in send_verification_notification
  24.     send_notification(notification)

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_registration/notifications/email.py" in send_notification
  209.     notification.send()

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  291.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in send_messages
  103.             new_conn_created = self.open()

File "/home/fullnamedebian/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py" in open
  63.             self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py" in __init__
  251.             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py" in connect
  336.         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py" in _get_socket
  307.                                         self.source_address)

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py" in create_connection
  727.         raise err

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py" in create_connection
  716.             sock.connect(sa)

Exception Type: ConnectionRefusedError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I added email settings:

```
# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 8000
```

And now when I submit post I just see this in terminal: `[22/Sep/2019 14:44:54] "POST /accounts/register/ HTTP/1.1" 400 13646` (Its drawn with red font, if it matters). And webpage is loading infinitley.

Comment: The second error suggest that there might be a problem with your email settings. You should replace the values, e.g. `no-reply@example.com` and `front end-site` for your site.

Comment: @Alasdair I updated my question - I used correct email, etc in settings, but error still happens.

Comment: We don’t know your email settings so we can’t help you debug. Perhaps there is a different email provider you could use.

Comment: Here we go, I think now we are really near to solve this. I didn't configure any email settings for my project, so do you think if I will set console email backend, it will work? @Alasdair

Comment: Console email backend is just for development - it prints the email to the console instead of sending it.

Comment: Of course, I understand how does it work. I will test if setting up this will solve issue. @Alasdair

Comment: @Alasdair I posted email settings in my question as well.

Comment: You probably don’t want `EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'` unless you have set up an email server. And if you have, it would be very unusual to use port `8000` (since that’s the default port for many web servers like the Django runserver).

Comment: You should use your email provider’s smtp server, or consider using django-anymail with a provider like mailgun or SES.